# Export mysql data into csv file

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export-to-csv

Hi i'm trying to export the data from mysql db to csv file by making it downloadable in .csv form.

Here is my code :

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['Download']))
{
include 'conn.php';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("select * from table");
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$filename = "export.csv";

$f = fopen('php://output', 'w'); 

header('Content-Type: text/csv');

header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="export.csv"');

header("Pragma: no-cache");

header("Expires: 0");

foreach ($rows as $line) { 
    fputcsv($f, $line); 
}


fclose($f);
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="GET" >
<input type="submit" name="Download" value="Download" class="submit" />

</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, the browser asks the user to save the file as. and the file is also being downloaded but the download never completes and the csv file contains the data as well as the code. Which i dont want. It seems there is some error in the header. Please help.

Comment: `die();` after your PHP code

Comment: Why don't you try some GUI tool like Navicat (Native Application) or phpMyAdmin (Web Application)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting an `exit();` directly after `fclose($f);` -- otherwise it will include the HTML in the download as well.

Comment: It helped me exclude the html part but still the download isnt completed. Why is that happening?